# How to run xen hypervisor on a computer that only supports UEFI?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xen, uefi

I have tried updating the bios, disabling hyperthreading, adding xen.efi to its proper location within Ubuntu, building xen from source, etc. Yet I cannot get past the following error

```
a Xen panic stating "IO-APIC + timer doesn't work!"
```

Does anyone know how to get past this error? My computer cannot run in legacy mode so I cannot boot xen by default.

Comment: Interesting. Exactly what is this hardware? Be specific.

Comment: https://www.asus.com/Laptops/For-Home/Zenbook/Zenbook-Pro-Duo-UX581/

Comment: A consumer laptop? I wish you good luck with that. You probably will get absolutely nowhere unless ASUS issues a BIOS update that fixes the problem, which is a total crapshoot.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks for trying